# ASP .Net MVC 5 don't load CSS and JS files in new page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have render problems with my CSS and JS in ASP.Net MVC 5.
In my _layout.cshtml I have include allot CSS and JS with "link" and "script" tags.
I`m trying to display User details in new page, but page contains only text and no CSS and JS files have been loaded.

Model code:

```
public class DetailViewModel
{
   public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

View code:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.DetailViewModel
<h2>Detaisl</h2>

@Model.User.UserName
```

Controller method is showing the Details view code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
   DetailViewModel model = new DetailViewModel();
   model.User = UserManager.FindById(id);
   return View(model);
}
```

And finaly a method call from other list view, that shows all users in db:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.User.Id})
```

The result is a page with a text but missing all CSS and JS files.
What I have done wrong? Is it something my logic wrong, I`m new to web developing. Just trying to display user properties on a new page.

_layout.cshhtm

```
@using WebApplication1.Helper.Const

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<!-- bootstrap & fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/ace/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/ace/assets/css/font-awesome.css" />
<!-- page specific plugin styles -->
<!-- text fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/ace/assets/css/ace-fonts.css" />
<!-- ace styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/ace/assets/css/ace.css"
      class="ace-main-stylesheet" id="main-ace-style" />
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/ace/assets/css/ace-part2.css" class="ace-main-stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/ace/assets/css/ace-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!-- inline styles related to this page -->
<!-- ace settings handler -->
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace-extra.js"></script>
<!-- HTML5shiv and Respond.js for IE8 to support HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--Google char API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>

<body class="no-skin">
<!-- #section:basics/navbar.layout -->
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <script type="text/javascript"> try { ace.settings.check('navbar', 'fixed') } catch (e) { } </script>
    <div class="navbar-container" id="navbar-container">
        <!-- #section:basics/sidebar.mobile.toggle -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle menu-toggler pull-left" id="menu-toggler" data-target="#sidebar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle sidebar</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- /section:basics/sidebar.mobile.toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <!-- #section:basics/navbar.layout.brand -->
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="navbar-brand">
                <small><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i> @Views.appName @Views.appTitle</small>
            </a><!-- /section:basics/navbar.layout.brand -->
            <!-- #section:basics/navbar.toggle -->
            <!-- /section:basics/navbar.toggle -->
        </div>
        <!-- #section:basics/navbar.dropdown -->
        <div class="navbar-buttons navbar-header pull-right" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav ace-nav">
                <!-- #section:basics/navbar.user_menu -->
                <li class="light-blue">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </li><!-- /section:basics/navbar.user_menu -->
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /section:basics/navbar.dropdown -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-container -->
</div>
<!-- /section:basics/navbar.layout -->
<div class="main-container" id="main-container">
    <script type="text/javascript"> try { ace.settings.check('main-container', 'fixed') } catch (e) { } </script>
    <!-- #section:basics/sidebar -->
    @Html.Partial("_MenuPartial")<!-- /section:basics/sidebar -->
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="main-content-inner">
            <!-- #section:basics/content.breadcrumbs -->
            @Html.Partial("_BreadcrumbsPartial")<!-- /section:basics/content.breadcrumbs -->
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
                        @RenderBody()<!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.page-content -->
        </div><!-- /.main-content-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.main-content -->
    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <!-- #section:basics/footer -->
            <div class="footer-content">
                <span>
                    @Views.appName <span class="blue bolder">@Views.appTitle</span> &copy; 2015
                </span>
            </div> <!-- /section:basics/footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- slide to top button -->
    <a href="#" id="btn-scroll-up" class="btn-scroll-up btn btn-sm btn-inverse">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-up icon-only bigger-110"></i>
    </a>
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
<!-- basic scripts -->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='../Content/ace/assets/js/jquery.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
</script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='../Content/ace/assets/js/jquery1x.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) document.write("<script src='../Content/ace/assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
</script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- page specific plugin scripts -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- ace scripts -->
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.scroller.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.colorpicker.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.fileinput.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.spinner.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.treeview.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.wizard.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.aside.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.ajax-content.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.touch-drag.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.sidebar.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.sidebar-scroll-1.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.submenu-hover.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.widget-box.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.settings.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.settings-rtl.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.settings-skin.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.widget-on-reload.js"></script>
<script src="../Content/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.searchbox-autocomplete.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your Layout file?

Comment: yes, this is startup layout which implementing costume Ace theme

Comment: When the page is rendered, is it showing 404 for your requested files?

Comment: You didn't answer my question, are the requests for that content showing 404s

Comment: yes, chrome return: Failed to load resource {404}

Comment: And can you confirm the folder structure of your Ace files

Comment: I can see files in chrome browser, but when i try to preview the resource file it return 404

Comment: Again, this isn't what I asked. Can you confirm the folder structure of your files in the solution. I.e. Solution -> Content -> ...

Comment: Also, does it load for your home page, but not your details page?

Comment: Yes, i have no problems whit all pages, only whit this specific action in this specific controller, all other pages are loaded properly.

Comment: Are all the other pages located in your `HomeController`

Comment: This action was called from same controller

Comment: from localhost:49166/Manage to localhost:49166/Manage/Details/some id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`../` will go up one directory in your structure. So when you are on `/manage` it will go back up to the root, but when you are on `/details/id` it will be looking for those resources in your `/details` folder.

Replace `../` with `~/` and this will look for a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Youre using relative paths to your `JS` and `CSS` files.

Try changing the path's to either their absolute `url` or use the `UrlHelper` class.

`@Url.Content("~/Content/ace/assets/css/font-awesome.css")`

Answer (score 0):

its better to bundle the things which are in the same directory to make it faster than normal compilation... and please use

> ~/ instead of ../

for bundling:

> go to: project_name -> bundleconfig.cs

you will get idea once you visit... :D